# How can I search the whole object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a table and a searchbox. I want to search all objects in array. When I type John, I want two objects to return because they are in the first and last name parts, and they are in both fields.

For example:

```
myArray = [
{id:1, name:'John', surname:'Vardy'},
{id:2, name:'Pepe', surname:'Vardy'},
{id:3, name:'Phil', surname:'John'},

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `filter` with a search in `Object.values`:

```
found = myArray.filter(obj =>
   Object.values(obj).includes(searchString))
```